# Inequality combined with divisibility relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $k$ and $m$, where $k>m$, be positive integers such that $$k^3-m^3 \vert  km(k^2-m^2).$$
Prove that ($k-m)^3>3km$

I established that $k^3-m^3<km(k^2-m^2)$, which gives $k^2+m^2+km<km(k+m)$.
By AMGM $3km<k^2+m^2+km$.

Could someone give me a hint?
I'm stuck but I would like to solve it by myself.

Comment: Have you tried using the general solution in the [answer](/a/4839426) that I provided to your earlier related question, in particular using inequalities based on the lower limits of certain values? Note I've confirmed that this does work. However, I won't post an answer here since you've stated that you would like to solve it yourself.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  I think I've got it. I posted my solution below. Could you please confirm my solution? Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome for my assistance. It's great that you tried to get a solution using the forms for $k$ and $m$ that solve $k^3 - m^3 \mid km(k^2 - m^2)$. Unfortunately, as I stated in my answer, the expressions for $k$ and $m$ you're using are *only* a special case. Nonetheless, you've got the right general idea with what you've shown in your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4839941/602049). I suggest you now try to use the full general form I give in my $(5)$ to reach the same conclusion.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I think now it's right

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got now a solution.
[With the expressions for k,and m from this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4839426)

Set $k=dk_1$, $m=dm_1$ and $d=n(k_{1}^2+k_1m_1+m_{1}^2)$.
Then the inequality becomes:
$3d^2k_1m_1<((k_1-m_1)(d))^3$

Which is equivalent to 
$3k_1m_1<(k_1-m_1)^3d$

Since by AmGm $3k_1m_1\leq3nk_1m_1<d$ and $(k_1-m_1)>0$ the inequality holds.

Comment: Good work. This is basically correct, but there are a few minor issues. We have $3k_{1}m_{1} \le 3nk_{1}m_{1}$, since $n\ge 1$, not $3k_{1}m_{1} \lt 3nk_{1}m_{1}$, and also this is not due to the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality). Also, FYI, instead of using the AM-GM inequality to show $3k_{1}m_{1} \lt k_1^2+k_{1}m_{1}+m_1^{2}$, another method is to use $(k_1-m_1)^2\gt 0\;\to\;k_1^2+2k_{1}m_{1}+m_1^2\gt 0\;\to\;k_1^2+k_{1}m_{1}+m_1^2\gt 3k_{1}m_{1}$.

Comment: FYI, here's the way I solved it myself. I used $(k-m)^3-3km=d^2(d(k_1-m_1)^3-3k_{1}m_{1})\ge d^2(d-3k_{1}m_{1})\ge d^2(k_1^2+k_{1}m_{1}+m_1^2-3k_{1}m_{1})=d^2(k_1^2-2k_{1}m_{1}+m_1^2)=d^2(k_1-m_1)^2\gt 0$

Comment: Thank you! Could you maybe recommend some resources for elementary number theory?

Comment: You're welcome. First, note I made a typo in my earlier [comment](/questions/4839896/inequality-combined-with-divisibility-relation?noredirect=1#comment10307950_4839941) in that my $k_1^2\color{red}{+}2k_{1}m_{1}+m_1^2\gt 0$ should be $k_1^2\color{red}{-}2k_{1}m_{1}+m_1^2\gt 0$ instead. Regarding resources for elementary number theory, I don't have any specific recommendations as I've not used any such material myself recently. Nonetheless, a [site search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=elementary+number+theory+resources) gives several potentially useful questions to check, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Very elementary number theory and combinatorics books.](/q/837852) and [which texts on number theory do you recommend?](/q/374662). They provide specific recommendations, links to other site questions, and external resources, such as the AoPS, i.e., [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com). Note the AoPS is also a quite good resource for high school math olympiad problems and solutions, where some of them involve challenging elementary number related questions.